# How can I send messages to clients without polling?

Tags: google-app-engine, chat

Every example for GAE Chats uses some kind of polling.  However, if my GAE app holds a list of clients (in the datastore if necessary), perhaps I could avoid polling by sending a message to all these clients.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are talking about HTTP, the short answer is that GAE does not currently support it.  What I think you are asking about is sometimes called [BOSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BOSH).  Once [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets) become more widespread, they will be an excellent solution for this problem.

In the mean time you might want to look at [XMPP](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/using_xmpp.html).  Using XMPP you can avoid polling.  Google has announced a [Channel API](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/05/app-engine-at-google-io-2010.html) (yet to be released) which will basically give you the same features as websockets.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably seen some chat room examples...

Since you just want to send a message to users on your datastore (Tip: the [IMProperty](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#IM) is great to store such data), it's just a matter of directly sending the message:

```
from google.appengine.api import xmpp
# `destination` is a list of JIDS
# `message` is a normal unicode string
xmpp.send_message(destination, message)
```

You can find a great tutorial on using XMPP by Nick Johnson [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/using_xmpp.html)

Comment: so when i integrate the chat into my application i could send messages to the users using xmpp and jids like: whatever@upserip:userport. Then my app sends my message as a http request. correct? can i traverse NAT like that?

Comment: @Laures now you got me confused. From what I understand, what you're looking for is actually on Robert's anwer, not mine. I'll be upvoting his answer.

Comment: ok...now i'm confused. I want to recieve information from clients and distribute recieved data to all clients. i want to do this without polling. when the channel api is out this should be simple, but why is it imposible now? (maybe i should have mentioned that this is my first gae or network related project)

Comment: It is not impossible now.  You could potentially use XMPP in combination with some thing like Strophe (http://code.stanziq.com/strophe/) to achieve what you want to.  What you are looking for is actually detailed in my response to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can now use the App Engine Channel API for this: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/

You can create a channel for a given client using:

```
channel.create_channel(client_id)
```

Then when you want to update that client, send a message:

```
channel.send_message(client_id, message)
```

Basically each client will get a persistent connection that you can push messages over.